# A puzzle on orthogonal matrices modulo $p$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I'm interested in orthogonal matrices over the ring $\def\Z{\mathbb Z}\def\F{\mathbb F}\F_p := \Z/p\Z$. Here, I mean orthogonal with respect to the usual dot-product: an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ is orthogonal if $M^{\;\!\!\mathsf T\!} M = I$, or equivalently if
$$ (M\mathbf x)\cdot(M\mathbf y) = \mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y$$
for all vectors $\mathbf x,\mathbf y \in \F_p^n$. I'm engaged in a technical bit of research involving such matrices, which — I suspect — may not require any more heavy machinery than results regarding quadratic residues, and perhaps counting arguments.

**Question.**
For $p$ any prime, is there a $4 \times 4$ matrix $M$ which is orthogonal modulo $p$, such that $M_{1,1} = M_{2,1} = 1$?

Comment: A necessary condition is that the first column, $(1,1,a,b)$, be of unit norm.  That is equivalent to $a^2+b^2=-1\pmod{p}$ having a solution.

Comment: @vadim123: indeed, and such solutions are "plentiful" for all primes $p > 5$. The trick is getting columns which are orthogonal to that column, and which also have unit norm in their own right. (Here is where there is potential for a proof by counting arguments, though I do not know how I would move forward with one.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "plentiful" result; perhaps its proof yields some insights.

Comment: @vadim123: it's a standard result which can be obtained by counting the number of consecutive pairs of quadratic residues. See for example [http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0713, Definition II and Lemma 4].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking for is an example of an *orthogonal design* [[1](http://ro.uow.edu.au/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2117&context=infopapers), [2](http://www.uow.edu.au/~jennie/WEB/CRChandbook-comb.ps)] evaluated modulo $p$; the same construction will work for any modulus $N \geqslant 1$ and any value for the 2-norm.

Take any unit vector $\mathbf v = (a,b,c,d)$. We associate with this vector a quaternion with integer coefficients,
$$ q_{\mathbf v} = a + bi + cj + dk.  $$
Construct $4$-vectors for the quaternions $iq_{\mathbf v}$, $jq_{\mathbf v}$, and $kq_{\mathbf v}$. The dot-product of two $4$-vectors $\mathbf v, \mathbf w$ will simply be $\mathrm{Re}(q_{\mathbf v}^\ast q_{\mathbf w})$, where $a^\ast$ is the conjugate of $a$; by construction $\{q_{\mathbf v}, iq_{\mathbf v}, jq_{\mathbf v}, kq_{\mathbf v}\}$ are orthogonal in this sense, so the four vectors form an orthonormal set modulo $N$. One then takes $M$ the be the matrix with these four vectors as its columns: following the Wikipedia section on [real matrix representations of quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations), the explicit matrix representation is then
$$ \begin{bmatrix} a & -b & -c & -d \\ b & a & d & -c \\ c & -d & a & b \\ d & c & -b & a \end{bmatrix}.$$
(The determinant of this matrix will be $\| \mathbf v \|_2^4 = (a^2 + b^2 + c^3 + d^2)^2$.)

Comment: Taking $q \perp r \iff \mathrm{Re}(q^\ast r) = 0$ here, I imagine. This is super-slick.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap, yes, that is how you retrieve the ordinary dot product in this setting.

Comment: A follow-up question. Is there an easy way to see what the determinant of this matrix will be (is it special orthogonal)?

Comment: Actually, for a quaternion $q = a + bi + cj + dk$, the determinant should be $\pm\mathrm{N}(q)^2 = \pm(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2$ by a geometric argument. I suppose that inspection of the expansion of the determinant shows that the sign is $+$. (This is a sum of four squares using the fact that $\mathrm{N}(q)^2 = \mathrm{N}(q^2)$, but not of the first column.) I wondered whether positivity follows from the handedness of the sequence of quaternionic units in the construction (it obviously is determined by it, but a simpler argument that $(i,j,k)$ gives $+$ would be nice). Does it?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap, you got it, it is always $+.$ I checked the wikipedia version with gp-pari.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap, as to your first point, if you divide the 4 by 4 matrix by the scalar $\sqrt {a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$ you do get a special orthogonal matrix, which is why the determinant works out your way, as the matrix is 4 by 4 and so we multiply the determinant by the fourth power of the scalar multiplier.

Comment: The cobwebs are clearing a bit: it really must be a polynomial, homogeneous of degree four rather than two.

Comment: True, but a sum of squares anyway. Don't sweat it. I wondered whether such quaternionic techniques (and further Cayley-Dickson extensions for higher dimensions) hid subtle and powerful ideas. Clearly they allow trivial construction of orthogonal vectors from any single vector (where the $2\times2$ case is familiar from first year linear algebra); clever techniques for the determinant seemed plausible, but in the absence of any such techniques for the $2\times2$ case, perhaps the determinant-expansion observation is about the best one can hope for.

Comment: It is clear that this construction generalizes to matrices of any order $2^n$, using the [Cayley-Dickson construction](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/oct.pdf): for example, the $8\times8$ case would use the octonians, the $16\times16$ case would use the sedenions, etc. Thus for any "unit" vector (modulo any $k$) of size $2^n$, one may obtain an orthogonal matrix (modulo $k$) having that vector as its first column. Does this construction have a **name**?

Comment: After a short depth-first search on the relevant concepts and terminology, it would appear that these are examples of **orthogonal designs**. I hope you don't mind if I edit your answer to present the idea in more generality.